# How can i resolve this error "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to programming and python itself. I got stuck in code mentioned below
I tried troubleshooting it myself but no sucess.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,contact):
        self.name = name
        self.contact = contact

    def getdata(self):
        print ("Accepting Data")
        self.name = input("Enter the name of student: ")
        self.contact = input("Enter contact number: ")

    def putdata(self):
        print ('The name is:' +self.name,'Contact number of student you entered is:' +self.contact)



John = Student("blank",0)
John.getdata()
John.putdata()
```

Comment: what inputs are you giving? use `raw_input` and your problems will be solved. Or switch to python 3.

Comment: Have you tried using the python `format` operations? See https://pyformat.info/ and [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Comment: I switched to python3 and it got resolved

Answer (score 0):

I switched to python3 and it got resolved